# expand OS partition backwards

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

This is the state of my hard disk: I have win10 and ubuntu 18 both.
Partition 5 is the Ubuntu one. I want to expand it to the whole unallocated space.
Since it is the company laptop, I cannot format partition5, merge it with the unallocated space and reinstall ubuntu from scratch. There is a crazy amount of software and OS configuration I cannot risk to lose.
What is the safest way of proceeding?
[image]

Edit:
This is a Gparted screenshot. It seems Gparted is more powerful than I remember, I can define the free space preceding and following a partition, and the new size, of course. With that, I can basically move my ubuntu partition at the beginning of the unallocated space and extend it to the whole free space in one shot.

Edit: After the move and expand operation on partition 5 with GParted, this is the result of sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0AE1E074-DF5C-4105-809F-9F121CEC35DF

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1085440    1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1290240    1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1323008  206123007 204800000  97.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 206123008  834476031 628353024 299.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 834476032  842336255   7860224   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p7 842336256 1000214527 157878272  75.3G Linux filesystem
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Sadly there's no safe way manipulating partitions, and less if you have to *move* it, which is what yo can do, and then expand to the right. Before trying, backup your data and make an image of the partition. The other option you have is to create a new partition in the unallocated space and then mount your `/home` in that partition, so only the system will live in partition 5, and your data in the new partition.

Comment: Which software do you suggest for backup and partitioning operations? Your second option won't be possible as partition 7 is already my `/home`, I ran out of space in the OS partition itself.

Comment: I fail to see your problem, since your disk report says partition 5 is totally empty.  What are you afraid of losing if you just deleted the empty partition5 and remade it where and of the size you want?

Comment: @ubfan1  Seeing this image is from windows, we can't count on it to show Linux partitions properly.  It is showing both Linux partitions as empty/free instead of having data on them.

Comment: Would use a live Ubuntu installer USB.  Use gparted to make an ext4 partition about 40GBs in the unallocated partition.  Install 18.04 or 20.04 in new partition and can move/add what you need from old OS.  Can also make new /home in space left in unallocated.

Comment: @alfredopacino Did you ever move/resize p7?

Comment: not yet..the most urgent thing was to expand p5. I will eventually do it. Do you think turning off the swap partition is really necessary? Can't I just move swap and p7 with Gparted?

Comment: If you did the first part of my answer, then you're using a /swapfile, and the p6 swap partition is not used any more. Otherwise, yes, you can use `gparted` to resize p5, and move p6 and p7, and resize p7. Your p5 is way too big, and is wasted space right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SWAP

We'll move from using a static swap partition, to a /swapfile.

**Edit /etc/fstab**

`sudo swapoff -a` # turn off swap

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` # edit this file

comment out the line that looks something like this:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Save the edits.

**Create /swapfile**

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm nnG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Delete the old swap partition**

Use `gparted` to delete the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition.

## Repartition

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p5 right to make the partition ~60G (tailor to requirements)
- note: /dev/nvme0n1p6 has already been deleted
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p7 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p7 all the way right
- click the Apply icon